# Invalidate NSTimer when going back navigation not forward

Tags: swift2

I have an NSTimer that counts down from a number of seconds. The timer sits in the middle view of a 3 view process.

I need to invalidate the timer because I have found if I don't the app memory starts blowing out (strong reference).

I put the invalidate in the viewWillDisappear method however because there is one more view that a user can segue to this stops the timer and when the user comes back to the view the countdown is paused.

How can I invalidate a nstimer only if the user goes back in the view hierarchy and not forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
if(![self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up using self.isMovingFromParentViewController() but this pointed me in the right direction.